# Morse Code Translator - Can't seem to convert from morse-to-english accurately

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops

So I have an assignment due and I have spent ages trying to figure out a specific part of the problem, but keep coming up with nothing. I finally 'gave up' and decided to come here for a little assistance.

The question reads as follows:

*"Write a program that reads an English language phrase and encodes the phrase into Morse code or reads in a phrase in Morse code and converts the phrase into English. **Use one blank between each Morse-code letter and three blanks between each Morse-code word**."*

The bit I am having trouble with is the bolded sentence above. I've got the rest of the program working from English-to-Morse, but in reverse it just messes up.

Here's what I know is happening:

The Morse code for the letter **'e'** is **'.'** and **'t'** is **'-'**, and the letter **'a'** is **'.-'**, in my current code, if you were to input **'.-'** in the morse-to-english area, it's going to return the translation as 'et', which isn't right. It's reading each individual dot and dash, when what it needs to be doing is reading the entire block of dots and dashes and trying to find it's equivalent. I figured the one-blank and three-blanks in the question is where I am messing up, but I just can't work out how to implement this. I figured it means that everything prior to a single blank space will be read in it's entirety, and then the three-blank space will simply translate to a single-blank to ensure the English translation is readable as a sentence.

Here's my current code. I'm a new Java programming student, and have been told **I must answer this problem using arrays**. Thanks:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MorseCode {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      String userResponse = "";
      String english = "English";
      String morse = "Morse-Code";
      String phrase = "";
      String answer = "";
      int loop = 0;

      final String[] englishArray = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L",
                               "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X",
                               "Y", "Z", " ", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"};

      final String[] morseArray = {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..",
                             ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.",
                             "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", " ", 
                             ".----", "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", 
                             "---..", "----.", "-----"};

      while(loop == 0)
      {
          System.out.print("\nWould you like to enter a phrase in English or in Morse-code? ");
          userResponse = input.next();  

          while(!(userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase(english) || userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase(morse)))
          {
              System.out.println("\nInvalid response. \nPlease enter 'English' or 'Morse-code'.\n");
              System.out.print("Would you like to enter a phrase in English or in Morse-code? ");
              userResponse = input.next();
          }

          if(userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase(english))
          {
              System.out.print("\nPlease enter your English phrase: ");
              input.nextLine();
              phrase = input.nextLine();    

              System.out.println("\nYou entered: " + phrase);
              phrase = phrase.toUpperCase();
              System.out.print("In morse code, this is: ");

              for(int count = 0; count < phrase.length(); count++ )
              { 
                  for(int index = 0; index < englishArray.length; index++) 
                  { 
                      if(phrase.substring(count, (count+1)).equals(englishArray[index]))
                          System.out.print(morseArray[index] + " "); 
                  } 
              } 
          }
          else if(userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase(morse))
          {
              System.out.print("\nPlease enter your Morse-code phrase: ");
              input.nextLine();
              phrase = input.nextLine();    

              System.out.println("\nYou entered: " + phrase);
              System.out.print("In English, this is: ");

              for(int count = 0; count < phrase.length(); count++ )
              { 
                  for(int index = 0; index < morseArray.length; index++) 
                  { 
                      if(phrase.substring(count, (count+1)).equals(morseArray[index])) 
                          System.out.print(englishArray[index]); 
                  } 
              } 
          }
          loop++;

          System.out.print("\n\nWould you like to enter another phrase? (Y or N): ");
          answer = input.next();

          while(!(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") || answer.equalsIgnoreCase("N")))
            {
                System.out.print("\nIncorrect input. Please enter either 'Y' or 'N'.");
                System.out.print("Would you like to create 20 sentences? (Y or N): ");
                answer = input.next();  
            }
          if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
          {
              loop = 0;
          }
          else
              {
                System.out.println("Program ended.");
                input.close();
              }

      }
}
```

}

Comment: Here is a hint - what if in your morseArray you included a space after each string, e.g. ".- " instead of ".-"

Comment: have a look at String.split() and regular expressions. you want to split english sentences into words by any number of while space characters (\\s+) and then iterate over every character of every word. morse text you want to split into words by 3 spaces (\\s{3}) and then split the words up to characters by a single space (\\s)

Comment: Kharyam - Tried that, it results in the output being completely blank!

Radai - Looking into String.split() now. We've not covered that in class, but it does seem like it may be the solution to this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, using the advice given above. I ended up using String.split().

Thank you for your help! :)

```
import java.util.*;

public class MorseCode {

public static void main(String[] args)
{

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      String userResponse = "";
      String english = "English";
      String morse = "Morse-Code";
      String morseChars = "";
      String morseMultiWords = "";
      String morseWords = "";
      String phrase = "";
      String answer = "";
      int loop = 0;

      final String[] englishArray = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L",
                               "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X",
                               "Y", "Z", " ", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"};

      final String[] morseArray = {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..",
                             ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.",
                             "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", " ", 
                             ".----", "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", 
                             "---..", "----.", "-----"};

      while(loop == 0)
      {   
          System.out.print("\nWould you like to enter a phrase in English or in Morse-code? ");
          userResponse = input.next();  


          while(!(userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase(english) || userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase(morse)))
          {
              System.out.println("\nInvalid response. \nPlease enter 'English' or 'Morse-code'.\n");
              System.out.print("Would you like to enter a phrase in English or in Morse-code? ");
              userResponse = input.next();
          }
          if(userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase(english))
          {
              System.out.print("\nPlease enter your English phrase: ");
              input.nextLine();
              phrase = input.nextLine();    

              System.out.println("\nYou entered: " + phrase.toUpperCase());
              phrase = phrase.toUpperCase();
              System.out.print("In morse code, this is: ");

              for(int count = 0; count < phrase.length(); count++ )
              { 
                  for(int index = 0; index < englishArray.length; index++) 
                  { 
                      if(phrase.substring(count, (count+1)).equals(englishArray[index]))
                          System.out.print(morseArray[index] + " "); 
                  } 
              } 
          }

          else if(userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase(morse))
          {
              System.out.print("\nPlease enter your Morse-code phrase: ");
              input.nextLine();
              phrase = input.nextLine();

               String[] morseMultipleWords = phrase.split("   ");

              System.out.println("\nYou entered: " + phrase);
              System.out.print("In English, this is: ");

              for(int i = 0; i < morseMultipleWords.length; i++)
              {
                  morseMultiWords = morseMultipleWords[i];

                  String[] morseCharacters = morseMultiWords.split(" ");

                  for(int j = 0; j < morseCharacters.length; j++)
                  {
                      morseChars += morseCharacters[j];


                      for(int index = 0; index < morseArray.length; index++) 
                      { 
                          if(morseChars.equals(morseArray[index])) 
                              morseWords += englishArray[index];
                      }
                      morseChars = "";
                  }
                  morseWords += " "; 
                  morseMultiWords = "";  
              }
              System.out.println(morseWords); 
          }
          loop++;

          System.out.print("\n\nWould you like to enter another phrase? (Y or N): ");
          answer = input.next();

          while(!(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") || answer.equalsIgnoreCase("N")))
            {
                System.out.print("\nIncorrect input. Please enter either 'Y' or 'N'.");
                System.out.print("Would you like to create 20 sentences? (Y or N): ");
                answer = input.next();  
            }
          if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
          {
              morseWords = "";
              loop = 0;
          }
          else
              {
                System.out.println("Program ended.");
                input.close();
              }

      }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

So a word in the morse language would look something like this:

```
.- -... -.-.
```

Meaning `ABC`. Notice there are whitespaces between the individual morse characters. You should try tokenizing the input, in this case simply split the string on `' '`

```
String input = readFromSomewhere();
// individual characters, you can now look them up in your array.
String [] morseCharacters = input.split(" ");
```

Also if the input is more than one word, then you should first get the individual words, and from each word you could get the individual morse characters:

```
String multiWordInput = readFromSomewhere();
String [] words = multiWordInput.split("   "); // 3 spaces between words
for (String word : words) {
    String [] morseChars = words.split(" ");
    // Character can be translated.
}
```

For storing the individual characters, i think a `Map` data structure would be much easier to use (probably that's not allowed), but you wouldn't need a linear search for finding the translation for each letter:

```
Map <String, String> morseToAscii = new HashMap<String, String>();
morseToAscii.put(".-", "A");
morseToAscii.put("-...", "B");
morseToAscii.put("-.-.", "C");
// ...
```

This would map your morse letters to the english letters, so you lookup your letters like this, after you got them:

```
String letterA = morseToAscii.get(".-"); // returns "A"
String letterB = morseToAscii.get("-..."); // returns "B"
String letterC = morseToAscii.get("-.-."); // returns "C"
String notValid = morseToAscii.get("Not a morse letter"); // this will be null
```

Also, i don't know if you have got any object oriented background, but to avoid the code becoming unreadable, i would separate the translating logic from the actual reading from console, etc...

So if i were you, i would create a common interface for translating stuff:

```
interface Translator {
    String translate(String input);
    String translateCharacter(String character);
    String translateWord(String word);
}
```

Then implement it for both Morse -> English and English -> Morse translation:

```
class MorseToEnglishTranslator implements Translator {
    // implement the Morse -> English translation here
}
```

And

```
class EnglishToMorseTranslator implements Translator {
    // implement the English -> Morse translation here 
}
```

This way you could structure your code a bit better :)

Comment: While we have just started using interfaces, unfortunately I am only allowed to turn in a single Java file for this specific assignment. I'm also not familiar with Map data structures either, but I do know that the only data structure I can use in this assignment is arrays (single or multi). I will definitely look into using String.split() though, that certainly sounds like the route I want to go down with this. I really appreciate your help, I felt like I was going around in circles with this.